# What should I do with the user input?

Tags: c++

Alright, so i'm building something that adds 2 numbers depending on how many numbers the user wants to add. But, once it gets down to the part with the user input, b will just switch with what the newest to it was. So I can't do anything with it much less how to use it to add it.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void main(){

    cout << "How many numbers do you want to add? ";
    int a;
    cin >> a;
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i ++){
        // if i<= a doesn't work use i < a + 1
        cout << "Please insert an interger you want to add: ";
        int b;


    }    

}
```

Comment: You need to store it somewhere else. So you need to dynamically allocate some storage space to store the input values, depending on the value `a`. Have a look at [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/416/).

Comment: @ReticulatedSpline You don't have to dynamically allocate space. Just ask a single number at a time and add to the sum.

Comment: Er, yes, you're right, assuming that's all he's doing with the numbers. :)

Comment: It's not 100% clear what you are asking, but I am guessing what you want to do is. First input the number of integers you want to add. Then input that many integers and display the total of those numbers added together?

Comment: I guess that is what his homework is asking from him @PaulRooney

Comment: @ManuelArwedSchmidt  not homework my friend told me it was a good program to make to learn C++.

Comment: @deeup511 You have already accepted the users input on this line `cin >> a;` Why not do it again for b?

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have right now is that you are not storing anything inside int b. You are only declaring the variable. Try putting a cin inside your for loop to store the value you want the user to add, then add it to another variable.

```
#include <iostream>
#using namespace std;

void main(){

cout << "How many numbers do you want to add? ";
int a;
cin >> a;
int b = 0;
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < a; i ++){
    // if i<= a doesn't work use i < a + 1
    cout << "Please insert an interger you want to add: ";
    cin >> b;

   sum = sum + b;
}
```

}

Comment: Works great! Is there a way I can get it to say what you added equals sum like 2 + 4 + 2 = sum

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but I think what you want is something like this:
    
    cout << "sum = "  << sum << " + " << b << endl;

Comment: If you're asking how to keep track of the different numbers the user input, then yes, you can, but you will need to keep track of the numbers somehow. Either using dynamic memory allocation as I previously mentioned, or just by building up a string with the input values as you go along.